# Replacing Spark SQL with Scala API calls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a simple LEFT JOIN

```
spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |  a.*,
         |  b.company_id AS companyId
         |FROM profile_views a
         |LEFT JOIN companies_info b
         |  ON a.memberId = b.member_id
         |""".stripMargin
    ).createOrReplaceTempView("company_views")
```

How do I replace this with the scala API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

Below code will work for `temp views` as well as `hive tables`.

```
val profile_views = spark
.table("profile_views")
.as("a")

val companies_info = spark
.table("companies_info")
.select($"company_id".as("companyId"),$"member_id".as("memberId"))
.as("b")

profile_views
.join(companies_info,Seq("memberId"),"left")
.createOrReplaceTempView("company_views")
```

If you have already data in DataFrame, You can use below code.

```
profile_viewsDF.as("a")
.join(
    companies_infoDF.select($"company_id".as("companyId"),$"member_id".as("memberId")).as("b"),
    Seq("memberId"),
    "left"
)
.createOrReplaceTempView("company_views")
```

**Update** : `temp views` can also called using `spark.table()`. Please check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("srinivas",10)).toDF("name","age")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> df.createTempView("person")

scala> spark.table("person").show
+--------+---+
|    name|age|
+--------+---+
|srinivas| 10|
+--------+---+
```

Comment: Will this be a LEFT join or an inner join? Also if I have to do an INNER join what will the call look like?

Comment: I have mentioned ```left``` inside join.

Comment: It will be ```inner``

Comment: `profile_views` and `companies_info` are both temp views - will this still work?

Comment: Good Question, I guess for temp view need to be handle in different ways.

Comment: The issue also is I'm picking and choosing some columns in the final table and not all. I'm not sure if this code does that.

Comment: from the above question, he is selecting all columns from profile_views table & one column from companies_info , also need joining column. if you need more columns from companies_info just have to select before joining.